# ASP NET HTTP keep alive

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, tcp

Возможно ли держать http соединение как tcp? Мне нужно когда что-небудь приходит на tcp делать http response. Возможно?)

Comment: Оно и так TCP соединение :) протоколы смотрите, веб сокет например, я так понимаю вас некая незакрывающаяся труба к юзера интересует..

Comment: вобщем мне нужно когда что-небудь приходит на tcp отправлять json

Answer (score 1):

Да, возможно.

Стандарт протокола http определяет [заголовок keep alive](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_HTTP-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Большинство грамотных реализаций веб-серверов спецификации в этом вопросе следуют. Например, и в IIS и в nginx это уже есть, а это самые популярные веб-сервера под win и nix (для .core разумеется) платформы, на которых крутят asp.net (core) приложения.